# How to convert a base64 dataUri to Uint8ClampedArray without using HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a project where I need to convert a base64 dataUri to Uint8ClampedArray without using HTML5 Canvas. This is what I have came up with but I think the Uint8ClampedArray doesn't represent the pixel table.

```
function dataUri2Array(uri){
    b64 = uri.slice(uri.indexOf(',')+1);
    str = atob(b64);
    arr = str.split('').map(function (e) {return e.charCodeAt(0);});
    u = new Uint8ClampedArray(arr);
    return u;
},
```

Comment: you have to populate the array in the map(), not all at once after...

Comment: Just use html5 canvas--it won't bite you.

Comment: @dandavis Can you please elaborate? May be with a few lines of codes?

Comment: @markE That's not an answer!

Comment: You're correct...that's why I posted it as a comment.  Why not use html5 canvas since it is a good tool for the job?

Comment: @markE I meant, I was looking for an answer, not an alternative.

Comment: Why not use html5 canvas?  I ask because, as David Titarenco says, you will need to find/code multiple image decoders.  Each image decoder is hundreds of lines of code--at least!   I'm just trying to push you in a path of least effort instead of "reinventing the wheel".  Good luck with your project. :-)

Comment: I understand that this problem can be solved by simply using Canvas. But I am working on a platform that doesn't support Canvas rendering. Which is why I need to encode/decode entirely on my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't want to use `Canvas`, you'll need to implement encoding/decoding for various image types yourself. Your code will look something like:

```
function dataUri2Array(uri){
    b64 = uri.slice(uri.indexOf(',')+1);
    type = getImageType(uri); // *
    data = atob(b64);
    switch (type) {
    case "jpeg":
         arr = decodeJpeg(data);
         break;
    case "gif":
         arr = decodeGif(data);
         break;
    case "png":
         arr = decodePng(data);
         break;
    default:
         break;
    }
    u = new Uint8ClampedArray(arr);
    return u;
}
```

The `getImageType(uri)` function and all the `decodeX(data)` functions need to be implemented. Here are some libraries that might help: [jpeg-js](https://github.com/eugeneware/jpeg-js), [node-pngjs](https://github.com/niegowski/node-pngjs), [bmp-js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bmp-js), etc. Getting the pixel arrays from arbitary data is nontrivial, especially when dealing with non-raw types (i.e. `BMP`).

If you want to write the decompressors yourself, the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Compression_ratio_and_artifacts) may be a good introduction, but I also suggest reading up on [Shannon-Fano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding) and other kinds of encoding methods to familiarize yourself with the concept.

I hope you have a good reason for not using `Canvas`.

Comment: Example code for PNGs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60290944/832776